# What's the meaning of the last part of a redis url?

Tags: redis, sidekiq

A redis url may look like this:

redis://redis.example.com:7372/12

It is the schema part: 'redis://',
hostname: redis.example.com
port: 7372

What does the number '12' mean at the last part?

Comment: It's an index of Redis DB, see [SELECT](http://redis.io/commands/select) command for more info.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The last number is the database number